Why does std::unique_ptr access appear to be more expensive than a custom struct?
Please see: https://godbolt.org/z/4fqqMbebh.
struct Ptr {
    int* x;
};

int* custom_struct(Ptr p) {
    return p.x;
}
int* unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<int> x) {
    return x.get();
}

yields
custom_struct(Ptr):
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        ret

I was under the impression that unique_ptr's memory layout is the same as the struct I have defined here. Could somebody explain why the unique_ptr access loads from memory (i.e. [rdi]) whereas the custom struct case can simply load rdi (what I expected unique_ptr to look like)?

just add a destructor to your struct ~Ptr() { delete x; } and you will see identical generated code

The more important problem is that your  unique_ptr is UB. The returned value refers to a deleted pointer. This is a very improper use of  get function.

std::unique_ptr has a non-trivial destructor. This implies that the compiler is not allowed to introduce any temporary object when passing to the function per C++ standard. As a consequence std::unique_ptr can't be passed in a register, which would require performing a disallowed copy if the std::unique_ptr is constructed on the call site from a prvalue expression.
What you see here is that your type with trivial destructor is passed by register, while std::unique_ptr is passed on the stack.
